# Convert RGB Image to Grayscale and Display It (Python + Matplotlib)

Tags: image-processing, python, scipy

I just started learning image processing and I was trying to read a RGB image then convert it to grayscale. I was hoping for something like this:

[image: expected]

However, what I get was:

[image: actual]

I tried using both scipy and PIL but they yield the same results. Am I lacking of understanding about grayscale image here?

Using scipy:

```
from scipy import misc
car = misc.imread('image.jpg', mode="L")
plt.imshow(car)
```

Using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
pil_im = Image.open('image.jpg')
pil_imgray = pil_im.convert('LA')

img = np.array(list(pil_imgray.getdata(band=0)), float)
img.shape = (pil_imgray.size[1], pil_imgray.size[0])
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  This is just an RTFM question about [`plt.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) and, as such, is not a signal processing question.

Comment: It works for me: just use `misc.imshow(car)` instead of `plt.imshow(car)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `cmap` properties of the `imshow()` function:

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Use:

`plt.imshow(img, cmap = "gray")`